# Two's Complement Adder/Subtractor does not work correctly

Tags: fpga, vhdl, quartus

[image]Hi im From Colombia sorry my English. I am developing a simple project, a Two's Complement Adder/Subtractor for 4 bits. I have developed as follows but in the simulation does not give me the expected result and I do not know what the problem.TY

```
library IEEE;

USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity negado is
    port (
        Y, signo : in STD_LOGIC;
        S, Carry : out STD_LOGIC
    );
end negado;

architecture Behavioral of negado is 
begin   
    S <= (((not Y) xor signo) and signo) or ((not signo) and Y);
    Carry <= (not Y) and signo;
end behavioral;




USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity complemento_2 is
    port(
        --input
        Y1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
        Sign : in STD_LOGIC;
        --output
        Cout : out STD_LOGIC;
        Sal : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0) 
    );
end complemento_2;

architecture Behavioral of complemento_2 is --Después de la arquitectura definimos la instanciación correspondiente a cada componente
    component negado
        port (
            Y, signo : in STD_LOGIC;
            S, Carry : out STD_LOGIC
        );
    end component;  

    signal Caux : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);

begin
            ins_negado1: negado port map( Y => Y1(0), signo => sign, S => Sal(0), Carry => Caux(0));
            ins_negado2: negado port map( Y => Y1(1), signo => Caux(0), S => Sal(1), Carry => Caux(1));
            ins_negado3: negado port map( Y => Y1(2), signo => Caux(1), S => Sal(2), Carry => Caux(2));
            ins_negado4: negado port map( Y => Y1(3), signo => Caux(2), S => Sal(3), Carry => Caux(3));
            Cout <= Caux(3);
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: details ............??

Comment: I think you forgot the "as follows" part.

Comment: when the sign is 1 or 0 then the output always gives me the same value, that is, the output gives the same "Y" input. and it should not be like that, and I do not know why

Comment: the description of the output should be in the question, not in a comment .... please add it to your question

Comment: You haven't told us what you're getting, or what you expected, or how they differ. Nor have you posted the testbench so we can try to see for ourselves. Do I feel like writing my own testbench? Not today.

Comment: ok sorry, I have already added the image of the simulation, as you can see it does not do the desired work. It is assumed that when sign is 1 you must make the complement.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complex? (Not(Y) xor (signo)) and (signo) is exactly equivalent to (Y) and (signo). Was this intended? In fact, it's even worse, because this condition is 'or'ed with ((Y) and Not(signo)). The result will indeed always output Y.

(A and B) or (A and Not(B)) is simply A.

You may wish to map this out as a logic diagram first, then go back to the vhdl.